# ViewEncapsulation.ShadowDom not rendering css at all

Tags: css, angular

I am trying to use ViewEncapsulation.ShadowDom and my css does not get rendered,what am I doing wrong here,Only inline css gets applied what may be the reason for this.Please suggest.I can't share the code as it is confidential.

EDIT:
I tried below example

app.component.css

```
.test{
    background: green;
}
```

app.component.html

```
<p class="test"> HELLO</p>
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  encapsulation:ViewEncapsulation.ShadowDom
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';
}
```

But it renders from css file for ShadowDom in the above example.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, this is exactly what 'ShadowDom'-option does. It does create a shadow dom and encapsulates styles, so takes only the components styles and does not take the global / default styles into account.

[Angular - View-Encapsulation](https://angular.io/guide/view-encapsulation)

Comment: component styles is not considered,that is the main problem @phaen